# dealing with missing or invalid qOffsets

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I've got a custom gdbserver that sometimes is not able to give a valid offset in the response to qOffsets (for good reasons that I won't go into here). I'm trying to find a way for the GDB client/user to compensate for this. The user can determine the correct load offset though not until after the image is loaded unfortunately.

When qOffsets doesn't get a response (or gets a "TextSeg=0"), "info file" shows the various sections - as if the image was loaded at offset 0.

I try using the commands

```
section EX 0x00020000
section .xxxx 0x00025000
section ...
```

to manually provide the correct offsets for each section.

When I issue "info file" again, the correct offsets now appear.

However, "info address main" still shows the address of main as-if it was loaded at offset 0 - so somehow the symbol resolution is ignoring the "section" offsets I provided.

That is, I get:

```
(gdb) info address main
Symbol "main()" is a function at address 0x474.
```

but I should be getting:

```
(gdb) info address main
Symbol "main()" is a function at address 0x20474.
```

Is there a way to fix this on the client side?